# I want to assert "Total" from the response in RestAssured can someone suggest me how to do that

Tags: api, selenium, automation, ui-automation, rest-assured

```
Headers: Authorization=Bearer4796aea4838ce5487518c706d49cc847b57e4196b52f0921539697e2d44bf060Accept=*/*Cookies: <none>Multiparts: <none>Body: <none>200{
```

"code": 200,
"meta": {
"pagination": {
**"total": 1526,**
"pages": 77,
"page": 5,
"limit": 20
}
}

Comment: have you tried anything >

Comment: https://gist.github.com/asingh4305/0c3a89150cc1bef5763e1a10f8c43f15

Please chk this link what I have tried from myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JsonPath to get the value of an key and then assert

```
Assert.assertEquals(response.body().jsonPath().getInt("meta.pagination.total"), 1534);
```